# Array to string with AngularJS and Lodash

Tags: javascript, angularjs, lodash

I have an array ($scope.paxlist) looking like this:

```
[
   {"name":"Maria","chosen":false},
   {"name":"Jenny","chosen":false},
   {"name":"Ben","chosen":false},
   {"name":"Morris","chosen":false}
]
```

I need to take only the values from `name` and convert them into a string in order to be able to use ng-CSV properly.
The desired output would be something like this:

```
$scope.var = "Maria, Jenny, Ben, Morris"
```

Taking into consideration that I have Angular and Lodash already loaded, could anybody point out if they have already some tool to do this painlessly?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Using native **map** of javascript you can do it as bellow

```
var data = [
   {"name":"Maria","chosen":false},
   {"name":"Jenny","chosen":false},
   {"name":"Ben","chosen":false},
   {"name":"Morris","chosen":false}
];

data.map(function(obj){return obj.name;}).join(', '); // returns the expected output.
```

**Using Lodash**

```
_.map(data,'name').join(', ')
```

Comment: Lodash's `pluck()` has [been deprecated](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/Changelog#v400) in favour of Lodash's `map()`.

Answer (score 5):

Lodash offers [`_.pluck`](https://lodash.com/docs#pluck) to extract a property from a list of objects:

```
$scope.var = _.pluck($scope.paxlist, 'name').join(', ');
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [_.map](https://lodash.com/docs#map) or  [_.pluck](https://lodash.com/docs#pluck), like this

```
$scope.var = _.map($scope.paxlist, 'name').join(', ');
```

or

```
$scope.var = _.pluck($scope.paxlist, 'name').join(', ');
```

Answer (score 4):

By using Mrityunjay's answer, this is another version of the answer to convert array of string to string:

```
const _ = require('lodash');
const data = ['abc','xyz','123'];
const translated = _.map(data).join(', ');
console.log(`result: ${translated}`);
```